# MySqli adding multiple rows to db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

I'm sending data to a db from a web form but every time I run it the data is stored in the db in six new rows rather than just one.

The form is just a standard form with inputs for email/password and a submit button. The action of the form runs this:

```
<?php
// connect to db
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db_name");
if (!$link) {die('Database Error: Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}

// username and password sent from form
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = ($_POST['password']);

// encrypt
$salt = substr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), 0, 16);
$em = crypt($email, '$6$'.$salt);
$pw = crypt($password, '$6$'.$salt);

// insert to db
$insert = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$em', '$pw')";
$link -> query($insert);

// check succes/fail
if ($link->query($insert) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
}

// close the db connection
$link->close();
```

I know this brings up a question about sanitizing inputs with encryption/salting. [This](http://www.phpdevtips.com/2011/08/data-encryption-using-aes_encrypt/) page says that it's a reasonable method. Please feel free to bring that up, but I'm not really looking for an argument over best practices for sanitizing user inputs.

I'm wondering if anyone cal tell me why the data would be stored 6 times instead of just once. I changed the `$6$` to `$1$` but it still added 6 rows.

Comment: because you ran it 6 times?

Comment: No, I just ran it once and it adds 6 rows

Comment: I thought it might be the salting causing it, so I tried adding plain text into the db (just for testing), by removing the salting and sending the form inputs to the db without salting them, but it did the same thing.

Comment: I even dropped the table, then dropped the db and remade it. It's still doing it, so I suspect it might not be the db that's dysfunctional. I suspect there's a problem with the code somewhere but have no idea where.

Comment: I may have found what was causing this: I tested on Chrome and it's adding one row to the db. I was using Blisk Browser before. That browser is still adding three rows to the db when I run the insert query.

Comment: so YCS may be partially (or more) correct below

Answer (score 0):

You have some silly seo-friendly links implementation on your site that makes it run your php code on every reques, and 5 links to non-existent resources in your html.